# Removing elements from dictionaries while maintaining form

Tags: python, dictionary, time, append, 2d

I have a dictionary containing time intervals of multiple objects i.e. effectively a 2D array with time in the x axis and object in the y. I also have the same shape dictionary for stellar flux values to go with those times and finally I have a dictionary containing the Stellar ID's which is a 1D array of strings.

Along with these is a dictionary with '`FLAG`' values where if `dic['FLAG'] != 0` then the corresponding flux and time values are to be discarded.

Using `time_new = (dic['time'][np.where(dic['FLAG'] == 0.)])` seems to go through the 2D time dictionary appending each accepted value onto the the end of the next rather than simply removing those values which are unsuitable and cutting away at the overall 2D array form.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to tackle such a problem? Many thanks!

Comment: Use a `np.ma.MaskedArray` and then set the `.mask` attribute to `dic['FLAG'] == 0.`

Comment: thanks for the reply! so something like new_time = np.ma.MaskedArray(time, mask = dic['FLAG'] == 0.) ?

Comment: Yes, at least if all later operations support masked arrays :)

Comment: it looks to have masked almost all of the data which is unusual but I'll keep on digging to see what's going on, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you mean, so I'll give you a few possible answers/tips.

```
#The dictionary
A = {"a" : 1, "b" : 2}

#N1
A.popitem()

#N2
A.pop("a")

#N3
List = list(A.keys())
A.pop(List[(len(List) - 1)])
```

I hope you can take something useful from this.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way:

```
import copy
A = {'obj1':{'value':1,'time':{'FLAG':0}},
 'obj2':{'value':1,'time':{'FLAG':1}},
 'obj3':{'value':1,'time':{'FLAG':0}},
}
B = copy.deepcopy(A)
objs = B.keys()
for obj in objs :
    if B[obj]['time']['FLAG']==0:
        del B[obj]
print B
```

The result is:

```
{'obj2': {'value': 1, 'time': {'FLAG': 1}}}
```

Comment: Okay I see what you're doing there, maybe my understanding of dicts is not up to scratch but my time and flag dictionaries are separate from each other but for each time recorded, for each object, a flag value is recorded in the FLAGS dictionary. So i would be querying the FLAGS dict for non zero values and removing their coordinate equivalent values from the time dictionary if that makes sense?

Comment: @user8188120 Yes you have 2 dict. You can always use del to delete some items from your dict. But I think it is better to use pandas instead of dict.

Comment: Okay thanks :) I think I need to read into dictionaries a bit more but I'll try and get my head around the code you've added above